# Javascript lodash merge array items by first item

Tags: javascript, lodash

there is a way for merge array items by first item

```
_.merge({a: 1, c: [{y: 8}, {z: 9}]}, {b: 0, c: [{x: 5}]})
```

Result:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "c": [
      {
         "y": 8,
         "x": 5
      },
      {
         "z": 9
      }
   ],
   "b": 0
}
```

what i want:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "c": [
      {
         "y": 8,
         "x": 5
      },
      {
         "z": 9,
         "x": 5 // <-------------------------
      }
   ],
   "b": 0
}
```

I want merge a source object by another used like a model. In case of array the model define only the first item of the collection and the source object should reflect the first model item into all the collection items.

Comment: _“Expected”_ based on _what_? What should be the _logic_ behind this? Your example seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: Based on the example, it adds the X:5 to the first item in the array.  If you want to push it through all array elements you may want to have the c array, be a bunch of : `c: [{x:5},{x:5},...]`... because as of right now the result makes sense.  You would just need to make your array have the same length as the rest of c one would think.   Another option would be to merge everything, less that object, and then carry out custom functionality.

Comment: I don’t think what you want still deserves to be called “merging”, at least not in the way that term is usually understood and used. You might have to write your own little function to achieve this rather special case.

Comment: @misorude ok, i understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't actually do it, as it might be very confusing (especially when you've got an array with more than 1 item).

You can use `_.mergeWith()`, and manually iterate and merge array items.

```js
const mrg = (o1, o2) => _.mergeWith(
  o1, o2,
  (a, b) => _.isArray(a) && _.isArray(b) ?
    a.map((item, i) => mrg(item, b[Math.min(i, b.length - 1)]))
    : 
    undefined
)

const result = mrg({a: 1, c: [{y: 8}, {z: 9}]}, {b: 0, c: [{x: 5}]})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.mergeWith

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
    if (_.isArray(objValue) && _.every(objValue, _.isObject) &&
        _.isArray(srcValue) && _.every(srcValue, _.isObject) )
    {   
        let newObj = Object.assign(...srcValue)
        _.forEach(objValue, function(obj, index) {
            objValue[index] = Object.assign(obj, newObj)
        });
    }
}

let a = {a: 1, c: [{y: 8}, {z: 9}]}
let b = {b: 0, c: [{x: 5}]}
let res = _.mergeWith(a, b, customizer)
```

Result:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "c": [
        {
            "y": 8,
            "x": 5
        },
        {
            "z": 9,
            "x": 5
        }
    ],
    "b": 0
}
```